# Effective C# 2D lists

Tags: c#, list, object

I am creating a State-Manager for a program. Each state will have a ID and a State class. I can add as many stats as I want by using an Add() function. Using a Change(ID) function will get change the state to the one in the list with a matching ID. Then ander further calls to the Manager will refer to the set state.

I would like to create a 2D list as such:

```
//short = ID No, IState = Sate Interface all states are based on
List<short, IState> StateList = new List<short, IState>();
```

I think for C# I'd require to create a List of Lists to get a 2D but I am unsure as the Intellisense marks it as **List < T >** with T being the param. Is there a better way of doing this? I appologise if this is very basic as I'm very new to this whole List idea.

Comment: Is the question just whether you're allowed to have a `List<List<T>>`? Then the answer is yes.

Comment: Is this the best way to do so, or would a List of a structure of ID/States be better or any other method of doing so. *Edit: Updated question

Comment: If your ID is not part of your IState, you may want to use a `Dictionary<short, IState>`.

Comment: State Machine in c#? check out stateless from the creator of autofac. http://code.google.com/p/stateless/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace `List` with `Dictionary`. You want a key/value pair as your list item, which a Dictionary provides.

```
Dictionary<short, IState> StateList = new Dictionary<short, IState>();
```

You can then index into the dictionary to find the state you want:

```
// Retrieve State 5
var state5 = StateList[5];
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a Dictionary object?  These are great for name/value pairs.

You could implement it as

```
Dictionary<short, IState> StateList = new Dictionary<short, IState>();
```

then just do

```
StateList.Add(1, new State() { blah, blah });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `List<Tuple<short, IState>>` if you want.

However, if the order of the items in the list is not important to you, you can use a `Dictionary<short, IState>` .

If the order is important, but happens to be the ID (lower IDs come before higher IDs, for instance), you can use a `SortedDictionary<short, IState>`.